# Redirect in javascript: IF GET parameter key allow to stay on the page; otherwise redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, if-statement, url, redirect, switch-statement

How is the best way to write this code? We want to let people who know how to add the ?Redirect=No to append the url stay on the page and view it otherwise the person will get redirected to the new site or to a "we-have-moved" page. An example would help me very much in knowing how to detect the GET url use case. I am a noobie javascript coder so your help is much appreciated!

**Option #1**

- *USE CASE 1:* oldsite.mysite.com : redirects to new site Use case
- *USE CASE 2:* oldsite.mysite.com?Redirect=No : does not redirect and the page loads normally

**Option #2 (A more user friendly approach)**

- *Use case 1:* oldsite.mysite.com : site redirects immediately to new
  site
- *Use case 2:* oldsite.mysite.com?Redirect=No : does not redirect and the
  page loads normally
- *Use case 3:* oldsite.mysite.com/AnyOtherPage : redirects to a “we’ve
  moved page” and then after “x” seconds redirects to the new site.
- *Use case 4:* oldsite.mysite.com/AnyOtherPage?Redirect=No : does not
  redirect and the page loads normally

---

```
<script>

// Check if the GET url parameter of "redirect=NO" is appended to the url 
and redirect if there is no parameter defined.


$(function() {


  if (  ... //url equals oldsite.mysite.com ...  )

      //GET redirect=NO so do nothing and stay here

      window.location.href = "https://newsite.mysite.com";

     }



   else if ( ... //url equals oldsite.mysite.com/anyOtherPage ...  )

     //GET redirect=NO so do nothing and stay here

     window.location.href = "https://oldsite.mysite.com/we-have-moved";

  }

 });

</script>
```

OR would it look more like this?

```
<script>

switch(expression) {

    case n:
         //GET url contains parameter "Redirect=NO"
         break;

    case n:
         if (//url contains a child page name) {

          window.location.href = "https://newsite.mysite.com/we-have-moved";

             }

         break;

   default:
         window.location.href = "https://newsite.mysite.com"; 

 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment in actual code.

```js
var sleep =(ms)=> new Promise((res, rej)=>{
         setTimeout( res, ms );
});
var redirect = async (pathname, ms) => {
    if(ms){ 
       await sleep(ms);
       console.log('waiting for' + ms + '...');
    }else{
      console.log('immediate');
    }
    
    console.log('http://newUrl.com' + pathname);//location.href = 'http://newUrl.com' + pathname 
}

var main = (url, ms) => {
  var u =new URL(url);
  var sp = Array.from(u.searchParams.entries());
  sp.some((arr,i)=>arr[0] === 'Redirect' && arr[1]=== 'No')? '': u.pathname === '/' ? redirect(''+u.search,0) : redirect(u.pathname+u.search, ms);
}




main('http://oldsite.mysite.com?Redirect=No', 5000);
main('http://oldsite.mysite.com/AnyOtherPage?Redirect=No', 5000);

console.log('redirection cases');
main('http://oldsite.mysite.com/AnyOtherPage', 5000);
main('http://oldsite.mysite.com', 5000);
```